Group by clause with sum and percentage
I'm trying to extract some data from a SQL Server database and work with it to get some basic figures for a financial report.
Suppose I have a table like this:



ID
code
name
total
profit




01
aa01
Alan
209.01
54.46


02
aa01
Alan
121.19
21.02


03
ab75
Abby
67.66
5.44


04
ch03
Chris
998.67
100.32


05
ch03
Chris
107.43
23.33



I want to be able to select these columns as I have (see below query) and then group by code with the SUM of total and profit. From there I need to get the percentage profit to total which will give me my margin per customer.
The code part is unique to each customer so in theory using the below I'd have 3 rows for Alan (2 lines aggregated), Abby & Chris (2 lines also). This would give me an overall spend and overall margin.
So far I have the following:
select code, name, total, profit 
from jobs
group by code
order by total desc

But I can't get the group by clause to work. I've tried adding the other columns to the group by clause but it makes no difference. From there I need to figure out how to "add" a column to my output which is % so essentially profit/total*100.
If anyone can help - that would be marvelous.

You need to show us your desired results before we can assist.

And ideally add your sample data as DDL+DML so we can copy and paste out for testing.

You should be using aggregate functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

@TN Nonsense, NLN flag them.

As best I can tell from the text description, you are just missing your aggregate functions e.g.
select code, name, sum(total) total, sum(profit) profit
  -- Avoid divide by 0 using a case expression
  -- add an else clause if you prefer 0 to null
  , case when sum(total) <> 0 then convert(decimal(9,4), sum(profit) / sum(total) * 100) end PercentageProfit
PercentageProfit
from jobs
group by code, name
order by sum(total) desc;

Returns



code
name
total
profit
PercentageProfit




ab75
Abby
67.66
5.44
8.0402


aa01
Alan
330.20
75.48
22.8588


ch03
Chris
1106.10
123.65
11.1789



Fiddle

Thanks @Dale K, however I'm getting a divide by zero error which is self explanatory, however in SQL studio it shows a glimpse of the data then errors. Is there a way to ignore the error for now, some of this data is very old and there are many thousands of rows.

Enhance your sample data to reproduce the issue

I usually do / nullif(sum(amount),0)

@siggemannen case allow one to return 0 instead of null if one prefers.
